# How to get the width of the dropdown part of Combo Control?

Tags: java, combobox, swt

I am using a Gridlayout with 4 columns which has 3 Text and 1 Combo Control in it. The problem is I have set a particular width for each control but Combo sets its width as the one I set + the dropdown part (/). How can I get the width of dropdown part so that I can subtract it from the original width and the controls would have equal spacing between them?

Comment: You don't normally need to set widths with `GridLayout` the layout will do that for you.

Comment: If you want them all to have the same width, use `new GridLayout(4, true)`. That'll make every cell have the same width.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have a container whose GridLayout I have set it to (4,true). If I don't mention the width, it Text controls are very small although now their size perfectly matches. Any other suggestions

Comment: @greg-449 baz:  Any suggestions

Comment: Make sure you use something like `GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false)` for the text to get it to use all the available space.